# send a jquery callback function inside a variable

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function

```
    function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

    $(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
        $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});
    });
}
```

it's working ok
when I do:

```
 example('http://example.com/', "#divid", callback);
```

but I want to send the callback function inside the (callback) variable
i.e: instead of butting the $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true}); inside the callback function I want to send it:

```
 example('http://example.com/', "#divid", '$("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});');
```

and then the function must be something like:

```
function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

$(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
    callback;
});
```

but that's not working

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried callback();  ?

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that callback is : $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To pass the callback around, the variable needs to be of type function.  Any of these should work:

```
function example(file, targetwidget, callback) {
  $(targetwidget).load(file, {limit:25}, callback);
}

// Call it by providing the function parameter via inline anonymous function:
example('http://example.com/', "#divid", function() {
  $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});
});

// Or, declare a function variable and pass that in:
var widgetCallback = function() {
  $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});
};

example('http://example.com/', "#divid", widgetCallback);

// Or, declare the function normally and pass that in:
function widgetCallback() {
  $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});
}

example('http://example.com/', "#divid", widgetCallback);
```

Comment: to add onto this great answer, you may want to add validation to this as well, I suggest using jquery's $.isFunction() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/)

Answer (score 2):

you need to invoke the function inside the callback

```
function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

$(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
    callback();
});
```

Comment: but callback = $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true}); I will try it

Comment: you still need to invoke the function by calling it with ()

Comment: assuming the callback is indeed a valid function!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, callback);
```

Comment: it's not working because the value inside callback is text form jquery point of view

Answer (score 1):

well.. You do this way:

```
function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

$(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
    if(typeof(callback)==='function'){
     callback.call(this, 'other parameters');
    }
});
```

The paramenters of callback will help you to send data back to callback function. ATTENTION, don't forget the `this` keyword!

Comment: then... it seems that callback is really not a function :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing a text string you would need to eval it:

```
function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

    $(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
        eval(callback);
    });
```

Edit:

if you want to use call() you would have to do it like this:

```
function callback() {
    $("#widget_accordion").accordion({fillSpace: true});
}

function example(file, targetwidget, callback){

    $(targetwidget).load(file, {limit: 25}, function(){
        if(typeof(callback)==='function'){
            callback.call(this);
        }
    });

example('http://example.com/', "#divid", callback);
```

In order for call to work, you would have to pass a function and not a string. But by wrapping your jQuery expression inside of a function, it would be run when the function is called. Calling a function can be done with the .call() method.

Comment: answered 3 mins ago
googletorp
666●10 -> and we all know eval is evil!

Comment: Yeah, read my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153241/send-a-jquery-callback-function-inside-a-variable/1153272#1153272 . Just use call() instead of eval()